# Javascript .split(",") with MongoDB $in operator

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a string like `var myFruits="Apple, Banana, Orange"`.
 
I also have two MongoDB documents as `{fruit: "Apple"},{fruit: "Banana"}`.

I want to query the MongoDB with `{ $in: myFruits.split(",") }`.

When I give it like this, only the first element `(Apple)` is detected by the query.

PS: If I directly give the array as `{ $in: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"] }` it works.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get an extra leading space when you do that split , so it will look like `["Apple", " Banana", " Orange"]`

Comment: Thanks, bud. Found the solution from the answer below too. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to correct split from `,` comma to `,`  comma and space,

```
{ $in: myFruits.split(", ") }
```